# What does "the architect" mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

What does "the architect" mean in football (soccer) context?

MISS! More sharp play has City bearing down on goal once more. Silva is again the **architect**, driving forward unchallenged before finding Aguero on the overlap to his left. The Argentine elects to aim for Cech's near post, but miscues and sends his shot straight to the Cech's feet.

Comment: It's **architect** =  [***a person responsible for achieving a particular plan or aim***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/architect), as "extended" from the more common specific sense of *a person whose job is to design new **buildings** and make certain that they are built correctly*.

Answer (score 1):

"Architect" here means the "builder" of the play. Sports reporting is full of wordplay: they have to do something to make the fundamentally trivial interesting.

Comment: All these years on ELL/ELU I've been taking light-hearted pops at sports commentators (who do say some pretty "odd" things), but it's never occurred to me to point out that they *have* to introduce ***wordplay*** to supplement often boring / trivial ***gameplay***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I suspect you have not had many dealings with reporters. It tends to make you regard them with bushels of cynicism. And a nice bit of wordplay of your own.

Comment: I've listened to *lot* of snooker commentators (only ever on the Beeb, other channels seem incapable of televising snooker properly), and a certain amount of football. You get lots of regional accents and unusual turns of phrase in both, which I always find interesting. But I can't help being aware that most people are bored to tears by at least one if not both of those, as TV spectator sports.

Answer (score 0):

An architect designs buildings and public spaces. In this quote Silva is designing the way the play will unfold on the pitch. It's his decisions that  shape the course of action.